# Why i get FormProxyObject error?

Tags: java, zk

My code in short piece:

Executions.createComponents("page/articles/translation/editTranslation.zul", null, args); --> call a zul file where is a form.

editTranslation:

```
<window id="editTranslation"
        title="Nyelvesítés szerkesztése"
        width="50%" closable="true"
        apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
        height="auto" border="normal" minimizable="false"
        mode="modal" maximizable="false"
        onCancel="@command('cancel')"
        viewModel="@id('vm') @init('hu.gamax.viewmodel.articles.translation.EditTranslationViewModel')" >
    <grid hflex="max" style="border: none" oddRowSclass="non-odd"
          form="@id('fx') @load(vm.trans) @save(vm.trans, before='save')">
        <columns>
            <column hflex="min" />
            <column hflex="max" />
        </columns>
        <rows style="background: #fff;">
            <row>
                <label value="${labels.article.translation.title}"/>
                <textbox value="@bind(fx.title)" onChange="@command('unpublished')" width="100%"/>
            </row>
        </rows>
      </grid>
    </window>
</zk>
```

And its viewModel:

```
@Init
public void init(@ExecutionArgParam("translation") Translation translation,
                 @ExecutionArgParam("filter") FilterGUI filter,
                 @ExecutionArgParam("id") String articleId) throws NamingException {
    System.err.println("------EditTranslationViewModel init-----");
    initTranslation(translation);
    System.err.println("------EditTranslationViewModel init END-----");
}

    private void initTranslation(Translation translation){
    Translation trans = new Translation();
    trans.setAbstract(translation.getAbstract());
    trans.setBackground(translation.getBackground());
    trans.setTitle(translation.getTitle());
    this.trans = trans;

}
```

I dont know why i get always formproxy error....im new with zk framework... I tried to add Immutable for the class or the getter-setter of the translation class...and add empty parameter constructor for the model classes but it isnt working....Can anyone helps to me? Thanks a lot!!!

-----UPDATE---
I get this stacktrace for the error: (but for vm works the code and for vm.trans not....when i added @Immutable to getTrans()). And i dont know why :S
It is a big stacktrace but i hope i get the more important part and copy here.

```
Caused by: javassist.CannotCompileException: by java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/zkoss/bind/proxy/FormProxyObject
at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:170)
at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:507)
... 123 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/zkoss/bind/proxy/FormProxyObject
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass2(FactoryHelper.java:182)
at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:164)
... 124 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.zkoss.bind.proxy.FormProxyObject from [Module "deployment.kit-ear.ear.kit-ejb.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
... 131 more
```

Comment: Try to use vm.trans as the proxy. Using vm for proxy is never a good idea

Comment: Sadly, not working :S

Comment: possible to add stacktrace?

Comment: a minute and update

Comment: ahhh....i have to add @Immutable to the Translation getTrans() getter method....and works :) :) but thanks for try to help me :)

Comment: but for vm.trans not works :S

Comment: i update the stacktrace

Comment: first start is reading the following link, some important stuff there (As I suspect you are using ZK 8) http://books.zkoss.org/zk-mvvm-book/8.0/data_binding/form_binding.html

Comment: I updated to load vm.trans and save vm.trans and in row load fx.title....but i get the same error...:S

Comment: The error of classnodef is that some dependencies are not in the classpath while they where there on compile. are some dependencies in the wrong scope (ex provided?)

Comment: sadly no...everithyng is good in my pom

Comment: if you check your war => is zk-bind there and the correct version?

Comment: yes...every zk with 8.0.1.1

Comment: possible to put (relevant part) on github or pass to me so I can check?

Comment: Well i think i know what is the problem....this code not see my EJB layers Translation class....so zks war not contain the ejb jar file...thats why not see i think